# Как синхронизировать потоки с помощью событий?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, события

В основном потоке main создаются экземпляры потоков marker. Как отправить событие из текущего потока в основной поток main? А затем из потока main завершить экземпляр потока marker?

```
CRITICAL_SECTION critsect;
HANDLE startAllThreads;

int main()
{
startAllThreads = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, TEXT("StartThreads"));
InitializeCriticalSection(&critsect);
for (i = 0; i < threads_count; i++)
    {
        ghThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)marker, &i, 0, &dwThreadID);
    }
    SetEvent(startAllThreads);
    dwWaitResultClose = WaitForMultipleObjects(threads_count, ghThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    switch (dwWaitResultClose)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        printf("All threads ended, cleaning up for application exit...\n");
        break;
    }
  }


DWORD marker(LPVOID &index_of_thread)
{
    DWORD dwWaitResult;
    DWORD dwTemp2;

    EnterCriticalSection(&critsect);

    dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(startAllThreads, INFINITE);

    switch (dwWaitResult)
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
        printf("Thread %d reading from buffer\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
        break;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&critsect);
    SetEvent(waitAllThreads);
    printf("Thread %d waiting\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    // Ожидание сигнала от основного потока
    dwTemp2 = WaitForSingleObject(waitAll, INFINITE);

    return 1;
}
```